# Get filename and file size from directory without using recursive switch

Tags: directory, command-line-interface

I am trying to write a command script to do the following.  For each file in a specific directory, I want to get the filename and the size of the file.  If the filename is what I am looking for and the file size is greater than zero, I want to process the file.

I can get the filename fine but I cannot get the file size without using the recursive switch.

This code works but I don't want it to look in subdirectories:

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /s /b /a-d "%input_directory%" ') do (
   set filename=%%~nxf
   set filesize=%%~zf
)
```

I've looked around but have been unable to find what I need.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. Here's what I used to get the job done.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b "%input_directory%" ') do (
    set filename=%%~nf
    if !filename!==somename (set validname=Y)
    if !validname!==Y (
        for %%a in ("%input_directory%\!filename!") do (
            set filesize=%%~za
            if !filesize!==0 (
               log as empty file
            ) else (
               process file
            )
        )
    )
)
```